# How to rotate Excel sheet horizontally using C# with Excel interop?

Tags: c#, excel

I created an Excel sheet with different size of columns and in some cells their are images placed using Excel interop api and some third party dll (gembox).

Here's a screenshot of that Excel sheet:

[image: image of excel]

Now client want to rotate it horizontally because last column text getting outside of the sheet.

I tried with some existing answers, like using transpose etc.

Is there anyone who knows method to directly rotate sheet with the images pasted in cell?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.Orientation = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape; 
// here xlWorkSheet is your worksheet.
```